# Sync video recording from two iphone 6 or 6+

Tags: iphone

I use my iPhone 6plus as a high speed video recorder of my son's golf swing. Is there a way to record two at the same time? I would like to capture the swing from behind and directly across (we both have iPhone's).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, yes. However, it's somewhat involved.

One way would be start filming on both iPhones and then play a high-pitched sound of some kind. Then, later, you can use video editing software like Adobe Premiere, or Final Cut Pro (or even iMove, I suppose) to visually sync up the videos by looking at the audio tracks of both videos and aligning them up visually by looking at the sound spike created by the high-pitched sound played during recording.

This is kind of like what video professionals do when working with multi-camera setups. Not exactly easy. But technically possible, if you know how to do video editing.